# Is a .runsettings file required for Azure DevOps to run MSTest unit tests?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration, mstest

I have a .Net Core 6.0 solution that looks like this:

```
Solution
--Proj1
--Proj2
--MyProject.UnitTests
  --Test.cs
```

And had the following snippet in my azure-pipelines.yml:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  continueOnError: true
```

When a commit triggers the CI pipeline, I get the following error during the test step:

> ##[error]No suitable test runtime provider was found for any source in this run.

Which leads me to ask: is a .runsettings file **required** for Azure DevOps to find and run tests? Many examples did not include this step when showing how to set up unit tests in devops, so I thought the answer was no.

After adding an example .runsettings file and modifying the script to the following, I was greeted with a litany of fatal errors of other dll's not being found, which put me in an even deeper hole:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    runSettingsFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\MyProject.UnitTests\test.runsettings'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  continueOnError: true
```

Comment: Just searching for the error message including "azure devops", I found this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/4516 (although I'm not sure if this is the same problem).

Comment: Thanks @GregBurghardt, I saw that issue too but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by ditching the VSTest task and replacing it with a dot net core test task:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'  
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
```